# If a javascript function is assigned to a working link, will the function execute first?

Tags: javascript, networking, hyperlink

If there is a JS function assigned to `onclick` on a link that directs the user to a different page will the function execute before the user is brought to a different page?

Comment: How is it "assigned"?  The click event is processed before hyperlink navigation occurs, I believe.  (This allows navigation to be canceled.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, function is executed first (I assume you are talking about `onClick` function). To test try this:

`<a href="http://google.com" onClick="alert('Bye bye')">Google</a>`

Also, if the function returns `false`, page will not redirect.